# Unprotect sheet prompt for PW only when AllowFiltering = True

Tags: vba, excel

I have two very simple subs to protect and unprotect a sheet with a password. The Subs work perfectly fine until I add the "AllowFiltering:=True" Parameter.

When that parameter is added, I am prompted for a password when unprotecting the sheet. However, if I press Cancel, the sheet is unprotected (as it should be).

Hence, the password prompt seems completely redundant, but can someone help me get rid of it?

The two subs are:

```
Sub LockSheet()

If ActiveSheet.Protect = False Then
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="TopSecretPW", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
End If

End Sub


Sub UnlockSheet()

If ActiveSheet.Unprotect = False Then
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="TopSecretPW"
End If

End Sub
```

If I use this macro - without the AllowFiltering:=True parameter - I am not prompted for a pw.

```
Sub LockSheet()

If ActiveSheet.Protect = False Then
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="TopSecretPW", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
End If

End Sub
```

Bonus info: The filter and protection is working just fine with the parameter set, and I cannot unprotect the sheet from the menu without entering the correct PW. It is just that uninvited PW prompt that I want to bury.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with how you are checking if the sheet is protected.  ActiveSheet.Protect is a method, not a property of the worksheet object.  Instead of using `If ActiveSheet.Protect` use `If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents`.  ProtectContents is a property of the WorkSheet object and will return true if the sheet is protected and false if it is not.  Your revised code should look like this:

```
Sub LockSheet()

If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents = False Then
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="TopSecretPW", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
End If

End Sub


Sub UnlockSheet()

If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents = True Then
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="TopSecretPW"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You're brilliant - it works!... Although, I'm not sure I understand how that can explain that the code works fine without the filter parameter set, and that I couldn't unlock the sheet from the menu without the PW, but I could cancel the PW prompt and unprotect the sheet, when running the unprotect sub... Never mind that for now. It works and that's what matters... Thanks a bunch Again.

Comment: No problem.  It's interesting how VBA was handling your code... basically the "If" statement itself was trying to to the method of protecting or unprotecting your sheet.  Not 100% sure why, but somehow in Excel it didn't think a password was required to unprotect the sheet if the "AllowFiltering" property was not included.  As it was, your If statement said "If ActiveSheet.Unprotect doesn't work (equals false) then..." and since the command was working with no password provided, the inside of the "If" was never triggered.