# Retaining Existing Excel Worksheet Protection When Enabling Grouping

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to allow grouping in worksheets (EnableOutlining). Below is a typical example that allows it but it also resets all of the protection attributes as specified. Unfortunately I don't know what the existing attributes are. Is there a simple way of retaining the existing protection attributes when I set the grouping attribute?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
' Modified from http://www.clickconsulting.com/forum/excel-support/grouping-protected-worksheet
' NOTE: It is not necessary to unprotect a worksheet to change the protection settings.
' Reference: https://exceloffthegrid.com/vba-code-worksheet-protection/
' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37419714/unprotect-sheet-prompt-for-pw-only-when-allowfiltering-true?rq=1

Dim pw As String

pw = "Secret"
For Each ws In Sheets
   With ws
        If .ProtectContents = True Then
           .Protect Password:=pw, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
           .EnableOutlining = True
       End If
    End With
Next ws

End Sub
```

How do I retain existing settings rather than overwrite them?

```
.Protect Password:=pw, _
DrawingObjects:=False, _
Contents:=True, _
Scenarios:=False, _
UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
AllowFormattingCells:=True, _
AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
AllowFormattingRows:=True, _
AllowInsertingColumns:=True, _
AllowInsertingRows:=True, _
AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=True, _
AllowDeletingColumns:=True, _
AllowDeletingRows:=True, _
AllowSorting:=True, _
AllowFiltering:=True, _
AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
```

I'd welcome any comments on how to manage a hard-coded password too.

Comment: This looks particularly useful https://powerspreadsheets.com/excel-vba-worksheets/#How-To-Read-A-Worksheet8217s-Protection-Settings I will see if i can write something quick based on this

Comment: I so far have only been able to think of a one way to do this.... to write a set of If statements that test the True/False condition of each of the [protection properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/protection-object-excel) of the protection object for the current worksheet.

Comment: It seems wrong that original settings are lost when the protection is re-enabled. @QHarr - saving each property and retrieving is the only thing I can imagine too and will work. I imagined there might be some way of saving collection of all protection attributes properties then all except ones to be changed and changing those to be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little long winded but uses a function to collect the current protection properties in a dictionary and then uses those dictionary settings to set the protection when locking again. I haven't code for all conditions (listed at bottom). This could be revised to produce a dictionary of dictionaries to capture for the different sheets or deploy the function in a loop. I would welcome feedback on how to improve this.

```
Option Explicit

Public myDict As Scripting.Dictionary

Sub test()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Set myDict = WorksheetProtectionSettings(ws)

    ws.Unprotect Password:="password"

    ws.Protect Password:="password", DrawingObjects:=myDict("ProtectDrawingObjects"), Contents:=myDict("ProtectContents") 'ToDo: extend with other arguments.......

End Sub

Private Function WorksheetProtectionSettings(ByVal ws As Worksheet) As Dictionary
'tools > references > ms scripting runtime library

Set myDict = New Scripting.Dictionary

With ws

    If .ProtectDrawingObjects = True Then
        myDict.Add "ProtectDrawingObjects", True
    Else
        myDict.Add "ProtectDrawingObjects", False
    End If

    If .ProtectContents = True Then
        myDict.Add "ProtectContents", True
    Else
        myDict.Add "ProtectContents", False
    End If

    'ToDo: Add other conditions.......

End With

Set WorksheetProtectionSettings = myDict

End Function

'https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-protect-method-excel
'Password
'Worksheet.ProtectDrawingObjects
'Worksheet.ProtectContents
'Worksheet.ProtectScenarios
'Worksheet.ProtectionMode
'Protection.AllowFormattingCells
'Protection.AllowFormattingColumns
'Protection.AllowFormattingRows
'Protection.AllowInsertingColumns
'Protection.AllowInsertingRows
'Protection.AllowInsertingHyperlinks
'Protection.AllowDeletingColumns
'Protection.AllowDeletingRows
'Protection.AllowSorting
'Protection.AllowFiltering
'Protection.AllowUsingPivotTables
```

Thanks to @TimWilliams it seems I can also access those properties commencing with "Protect" via then [CallByName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/callbyname-function) function:

```
Dim result As Boolean
result = CallByName(ws, "ProtectDrawingObjects", VbGet)
MsgBox result
```

More info given on this in Tim's answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48275351/how-to-access-a-worksheet-property-using-a-variable/48287653?noredirect=1#comment83563124_48287653).